# Using a custom formula field to create a timezone adjusted field using an existing datetime and timezone field

Tags: formula, formula-field, datetime, timezone

We would like to use an email alert to automate demo reminder emails for our prospects.  We currently have a Demo Meeting Time field (datetime) and a Timezone field (text) to reference in a formula field.

Is there any way to use a custom formula field that references our Demo Meeting Time and Account Timezone fields to create a timezone adjusted field that can be used in an email template?

Answer (score 0):

Peter

If you can come up with a mapping between the Timezone text field and relative time difference in number, you can use the formula provided in [this salesforce article](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000181642&language=en_US) to get the datetime field in your required timezone.